# I want to find the covariance for an AR(2) process

Tags: time-series, self-study, autocorrelation, covariance

I am not sure what the formula is for the covariance of an AR(2) process
$$
X_t = \phi_1 X_{t−1} + \phi_2 X_{t−2} + \epsilon_t
$$
where $\{\epsilon_t\}$ is white noise process (Gaussian) $N(0, \sigma^2)$.

What is the formula for $\text{Cov}(X_t, X_{t-j})$?

Comment: I am asking what is the general formula for covariance, not autocovariance

Comment: What does that mean in this context?

Comment: Okay but note that it exists only if the roots of the characteristic polynomial fall outside the unit circle in the complex plane.

Comment: Check out the existing posts on the subject at Cross Validated. You will find either an exact same question or similar ones that will help you.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325137/autocorrelation-of-a-stationary-ar2-process

Answer (score 1):

Just use the bilinearity of the covariance function:
$$\operatorname{cov}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i, \sum_{j=1}^m b_j Y_j\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m a_i b_j(\operatorname{cov}X_i, Y_j)$$
to get
\begin{align}
\operatorname{cov}(X_t,X_{t-j}) &= \operatorname{cov}(\phi_1X_{t-1}+\phi_2X_{t-2}+\epsilon_t, \phi_1X_{t-j-1}+\phi_2X_{t-j-2}+\epsilon_{t-j})\\
&= \phi_1^2 \operatorname{cov}(X_{t-1},X_{t-j-1})
+ \phi_1^2 \operatorname{cov}(X_{t-2},X_{t-j-2})\\
& \quad +\phi_1\phi_2 \operatorname{cov}(X_{t-1},X_{t-j-2})
+ \phi_1\phi_2 \operatorname{cov}(X_{t-2},X_{t-j-1})
\end{align}
which gives a linear recurrence relationship that you can 
try and solve for
yourself, or read up on how to go about doing so in your book. A very general relationship for time series defined by linear recurrences is that
the "output" autocovariance *function* is given by the convolution of the "input" autocovariance *function* and the "autocovariance" of the characteristic function of the recurrence:
$$C_o = C_i\, \star\,  \left(\phi(x)\,  \star\, \phi(x^{-1})\right).$$

Comment: For $j>0$, the covariances of $\epsilon_{t-j}$ with $X_{t-1}$ and $X_{t-2}$ are non-zero so your second equation is incorrect.

Comment: The linear recurrence relationship mentioned by [@Dilip Sarwate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/6633/dilip-sarwate) should be \begin{align}
\operatorname{cov}(X_t,X_{t-j}) &= \operatorname{cov}(\phi_1X_{t-1}+\phi_2X_{t-2}+\epsilon_{t}, X_{t-j}) \\
&= \phi_{1}\operatorname{cov}(X_{t-1}, X_{t-j}) + \phi_2 \operatorname{cov}(X_{t-2}, X_{t-j}) + \operatorname{cov}(\epsilon_{t}, X_{t-j}) \\
&= \phi_{1}\operatorname{cov}(X_{t-1}, X_{t-j}) + \phi_2 \operatorname{cov}(X_{t-2}, X_{t-j})
\end{align}