# Estimate variance of a ARMA(1,1) with additional AR process in error term

Tags: time-series, variance, arima, autoregressive

This is a generalized version of a [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451706/variance-of-sum-of-ar2-processes). Yet, I have issues in extrapolating the (very useful) answers.

We have a ARMA(1,1)
$$y_t = ay_{t-1} + b\mu_{t} + c\mu_{t-1} $$

The particularity here is that $\mu$ itself is an AR process, let's assume here an AR(3)

$$\mu_t = \phi_1 \mu_{t-1} + \phi_2 \mu_{t-2} + \phi_3 \mu_{t-3} + \epsilon_t$$

where $\epsilon_t$ is a white noise process with E($\epsilon_t$)=0 and $Var(\epsilon_t)=\sigma^2$.

Now, I would like to estimate $Var(y_t)$. Parameters $a, b, \Phi$ and $\sigma$ are known.

**My approach so far**

1. Rewrite the ARMA process as an infinite sum
   $$y_t = \sum_{i=0} [a^{i+1} b\mu_{t-1-i} + a^{i} c \mu_{t-1-i}] + b \mu_{t} $$
2. Now, the challenge is (I think) to either

   - compute the variance of $\mu_t$ and loop over the infinite sum, but then we have to take into account a zillion covariance terms. [whuber suggests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451706/variance-of-sum-of-ar2-processes) how to do this with only 4 addends and an AR(2) - but how to do this in this general case?
   - rewrite everything in terms of the parameters and white noise $\epsilon$s and probably in companion form, as line by line this is becoming extremely messy.

The aim is to estimate the variance, so any pointer how to compute the approach (e.g. in R or Matlab) would be particularly welcome.

Comment: You say *We have a ARMA(1,1)* and then write down an AR(1) model with a redundant coefficient $b$.

Comment: Hi: What you have their is the sum of two AR processes and Richard makes a good point that $b$ is redundant. I can't help with the question but take a look at this for ideas on how to solve  it. http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~zhu/ams586/SUM.pdf. I'm pretty certain that you have an AR(1) pluis an AR(3).

Comment: Hi: If you have access to JSTOR, then below would be useful because it's the original paper that proves what the sum of 2 AR processes is. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2345178?seq=1

Comment: @RichardHardy you are completely right. Typed up the equations from memory and misspelled the MA part. I will update.

Comment: I don't quite see how this is a "generalized version" of the previous question so I voted to close.  You should instead post comments to the answers to the original question if something is unclear.

Comment: Well, the method of rewriting to the overall ARMA model for $y_t$ is more or less the same.  Using backshift operator polynomials you have $\phi(B)y_t=\theta(B)\mu_t$ and $\gamma(B)\mu_t = \epsilon_t$ from which you find that $y_t$ satisfies $\phi(B)\gamma(B)y_t = \theta(B)\epsilon_t$.  Expanding $\phi(B)\gamma(B)$ you find the overall autoregressive polynomial of the resulting ARMA(4,1) and its coefficients.  From there, the rest is as in my answer to your other question.

Comment: @JarleTufto this question is different for (i) the original question focuses on  not what is in principal a ARMA process, here we have an ARMA with AR processes in the MA components; (ii) therefore we have covariance terms in an infinite amount of addends, not only 4. In my view, this merits a separate question but please advise if not

Comment: @JarleTufto Thank you! Let me look at this.

Comment: $b$ is still redundant. I think you cannot identify both $b$ and the variance of $\mu_t$, just their ratio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variance of sum of AR(2) processes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451706/variance-of-sum-of-ar2-processes)