# How to calculate variance of AR(1) process

Tags: regression, time-series, variance, stationarity

I have a stationary AR(1) process: $Z_t = \alpha_{1}Z_{t-1} + \nu_{t}$, where $\nu_t$ is white noise and $|\alpha_1| < 1$.

I have to show that the variance of $\Delta Z_t$ is $$V[\Delta Z_t] = 2\sigma^2_\nu /(1+\alpha_1).$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265478 shows the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to write the difference in terms of the original model:
$$ \Delta Z_t = Z_{t} - Z_{t-1} = (\alpha-1)Z_{t-1} + \nu_t $$
Since $Z_{t-1}$ and $\nu_t$ are uncorrelated by the white noise assumption,
$$ \mathbb{V}(\Delta Z_t) = (\alpha-1)^2\mathbb{V}(Z_{t-1}) + \mathbb{V}(\nu_t).$$
The hard part is to find $\mathbb{V}(Z_{t-1})$. By evaluating the model recursively,
$$ Z_{t-1} = \alpha Z_{t-2} + \nu_{t-1} \implies  \mathbb{V}(Z_{t-1}) = \alpha^2\mathbb{V}(Z_{t-2}) + \mathbb{V}(\nu_{t-1}) $$

If the process is stationary, then the unconditional variance is constant over time, which means that $\mathbb{V}(Z_{t-1}) = \mathbb{V}(Z_{t-2})$. Substituting this value, and the variance of the error:
$$ \mathbb{V}(Z_{t-1}) = \alpha^2\mathbb{V}(Z_{t-1}) + \sigma_{\nu}^2.
$$
If $|\alpha| < 1$, then a unique solution exists and is equal to $\mathbb{V}(Z_{t-1}) = \frac{\sigma_\nu^2}{1-\alpha^2}$.

To complete the proof we simply need to substitute the result:
\begin{align*} \mathbb{V}(\Delta Z_t) &=  \frac{(\alpha-1)^2\sigma_{\nu}^2}{1-\alpha^2} + \sigma_{\nu}^2 \\ 
&= \frac{-(\alpha-1)\sigma_{\nu}^2}{1+\alpha} + \sigma_{\nu}^2 \\
&= \frac{2\sigma_\nu^2}{1+\alpha}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much, with your explanation, I understand the problem much clearly now.  Recursive method was what I was struggling with the most.